# Converting a string into a formatted data (to create bibitem from .bib file)

Tags: string-manipulation

Say I have a string like this

```
article{a2,
  author  = {F1name L1name, F2name M2name L2name}, 
  title   = {The title of the work},
  journal = {The Journal2},
  year    = 1994,
  number  = 3,
  pages   = {204-223},
  month   = 6,
  note    = {An optional note}, 
  volume  = 2
}
```

This is how the input looks like in notebook.

> "article{a2,\n  author  = {F1name L1name, F2name M2name L2name}, \n  title   \
>   = {The title of the work},\n  journal = {The Journal2},\n  year    = 1994,\n \
>    number  = 3,\n  pages   = {204-223},\n  month   = 6,\n  note    = {An \
>   optional note}, \n  volume  = 2\n}"

How can I store these data a variable `entry` like this

```
entry["a2"]={"a2", "article", "F1name L1name, F2name M2name L2name",
             "The title of the work","The Journal2","2","204-223","1994"}
```

I have to maintain the order

> entry [ key] = {key, type, author, title, journal, volume, pages, year}

---

### **Why I am doing this !**

As you probably recognise that I am trying to create bibliographic items from a `.bib` file (check this Wikipedia entry on [BibTex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibTeX) for more details). Above is an entry you get when you run

```
StringSplit[Import["a.bib"], "@"][[2]]
```

Then I define a style

```
shortname[name_] := Module[{nparts},
 nparts = StringSplit[name];
 StringJoin[ ToString[StringForm["``. ", StringTake[#, 1]]] & /@ 
 nparts[[1 ;; -2]], ToString[nparts[[-1]]]]]

authornames[authors_] := Module[{n, names},
 names = shortname[#] & /@ Flatten[StringSplit[authors, ","]];
 n = Length[names];
 If[n > 1, StringJoin[ToString@StringForm["``, ", #] & /@ names[[1 ;; -2]], 
"and ", ToString[names[[-1]]]], names]]

abbvr["The Journal2"] = "T. Jour2"; (*Journal abbreviation*)

article[s_List] := StringForm["\\bibitem{``} ``, \\textit{``},
                                   `` \\textbf{``}, `` (``).", 
 authornames[s[[2]]], s[[3]], abbvr[s[[4]]], s[[5]], 
 StringSplit[s[[6]], "-"][[1]], s[[7]]]

article[entry["a2"]]
```

> \bibitem{a2} F. L1name, and F. M. L2name, \textit{The title of the work}, T. Jour2 \textbf{2}, 204 (1994).

and you are ready to go. It is much easier than messing with a gigantic [.bst](http://www.esa.int/esapub/conference/unsrt.bst) file.

Comment: Are there newlines (`\n`'s) hidden in the string after every comma?

Comment: you are right @march (did not thought about that before). I put the `InputForm` in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a job for associations:

```
input = "article{a2,author={F1name L1name,F2name M2name,L2name},
 title={The title of the work},
 journal={The Journal2},year=1994,
 number=3,pages={204-223},month=6,
 note={An optional note},volume=2}"

type = StringCases[input, 
     Shortest[StartOfString ~~ t : __ ~~ "{"] :> t][[1]]
```

> "article"

```
key = StringCases[input, 
  Shortest[StartOfString ~~ __ ~~ "{"] ~~ key : Shortest[__] ~~  "," :> key][[1]]
```

> "a2"

```
a["a2"] = Association["type" -> type, "key" -> key]

a[key] = Append[a[key],
 Association[
   Flatten[StringCases[
     input, (k : Except["," | "\n"] ..) ~~ "=" ~~ 
       v : ("{" ~~ Except["}"] .. ~~ "}") :> {k -> v}]]]~Join~
 Association[
   Flatten[StringCases[
     input, (k : Except["," | "\n"] ..) ~~ "=" ~~ 
       v : NumberString :> {k -> v}]]]]

 a["a2"]["pages"]
```

> "{204-223}"

Comment: Thanks george. Actually I missed `\n` in my question (@march pointed out that).  Could you modify your answer for that :). I put the `InputForm` of the entry in my question.

Comment: I think the way i did it, it should not care if you have embedded newlines or not.